# Как добавить текст внизу кнопки в react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Использую react-js и библиотеку https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/

Мне нужно создать компонент, представляющий из себя кнопку, которая в верхней половине содержит иконку, а в нижней - текст

```
import React from "react";
import {withStyles} from "material-ui/styles";
import Settings from "material-ui-icons/Settings";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";

const IconedLabel = ({classes}) => (
<section>
    <Button className={classes.iconButton} variant="raised" color="primary">
        <Settings className={classes.icon}/>
        <div className={classes.text}>Message</div>
    </Button>
</section>);
```

Cейчас использую такой способ, но не выполняется отрисовка под иконкой(смещено вправо как показано на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Запиши в стили iconButton следующее:

```
iconButton: {
    display: flex,
    flex-direction: column,
    align-items: center,
    justify-content: center
}
```

Можно еще использовать для этого Material UI Grids, ссылка на документацию: https://material-ui-next.com/layout/grid/